# Android HTTPS-connection with own certificates

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, certificate

Before: I've already tried this: [Provide own root-certificate for HTTPS-connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217513/provide-own-root-certificate-for-https-connection) and this [Security with HTTPS and SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) and some over stackoverflow-questions.

Former, I used HTTP to send POST-Data to the server. But now I want to change to HTTPS/SSL due to security reasons.

That's my code so far:

```
CertificateFactory cf =CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStreamcaInput caInput= new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crtsrv));
Certificate ca;
try{
  ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
  System.out.println(((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
//This returns: OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#161C6265726E642E6672697363686D616E6E406F75746C6F6F6B2E636F6D, CN=IP, OU=UNIT, O=ORGANISATION, L=CITY, ST=STATE, C=AU
}finally{
  caInput.close();
}
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null,null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cn", ca);
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
//The statement above throws the exception, look down!

urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
//After this there is the Outputstreamwriter & Bufferedreader to write
//and read the answer from the server,
//so far there is an exception above!
```

Exception 1 solved: String link started with http:// and not https://

> **EDIT New exception:**
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

What should solve the problem?

Comment: seems like the `link` schema is http not https

Comment: Okay, solved the exception. I edit the new exception...

Comment: what is R.raw.crtsrv ? Self-signed server certificate in bk store ? if so then the code wrong

Comment: It's an generated crt by makecert.bat from XAMPP. So what shall I do?
I want is to send data via HTTPS or SSL to the Server to login, more or less. There are also available: server.key or server.csr!

Comment: ok, i did only use self signed certs to ensure that the server is the one that i wana to connect ... so i can't help you with this ... but one  thing that i had problems was that AndroidOpenSSL(which is default implementation on API >19) is not working well on Intel x64 emulator (works on Intel x86)

Comment: This certificate is self signed! The signature algorithm is sha1 (RSA)
I use my own S4 to debug the app!

Comment: @Selvin Did you read my last comment

Comment: yes, i did...try http://selvin.pl/HTTPSUtils.java.txt (keystore should be keystore.bks in raw) then use `urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(HTTPSUtils.getSSLSocketContext(somecontext_activity_service_application).getSocketFactory());` get cer file from browser(open https site and save the certificate) then use `keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "path_to_cert/interm_ca.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "res/raw/keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "path_to_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass password`

Comment: And how can I use the HTTPSUtils?

Comment: there is the usage in prev comment ...